# How do I set Jasper init parameters globally for all servlets in Tomcat's web.xml?

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets, web.xml

I'm using [Tomcat's Jasper HowTo](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jasper-howto.html) to set init parameters for my servlets.  But I haven't figured out how to set these parameters globally in the web.xml file.  How do I avoid duplicating my init-params in every servlet description?

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         metadata-complete="true">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>foo</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/foo/foo.jsp</jsp-file>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>compilerTargetVM</param-name>
            <param-value>1.7</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>bar</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/bar/bar.jsp</jsp-file>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>compilerTargetVM</param-name>
            <param-value>1.7</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the answer is in the linked document:

> The servlet which implements Jasper is configured using init parameters in your global `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/web.xml`

So open this file and add the appropriate init-params in the Jasper servlet (`<servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>`).

This will set the parameters for the entire server. I haven't tried to set the parameters for just one application; it *may* be possible to repeat the declaration of the jsp servlet *and* mapping from the global web.xml to your own and add the init-params. (However, for the param you are setting, `compilerTargetVM`, it does make sense to apply it globally to the entire server.)

---

I had no Tomcat available so I tested right now with Tomcat version 7.0.47: You **can** add the `<servlet>jsp</servlet>` in the web.xml of the application (copying it from the global conf/web.xml and modifying what you want) and it **DOES** work. I.e. all the JSPs in this application run with the desired init-params, while other applications are unaffected.

Comment: @Nikos: have you found any reference in docs about this behaviour? I thought this is a global setting and I was surprised that it works now on application web.xml too. Tried it locally and indeed it seems working.

Comment: @rlegendi Actually no, but my thought process is that, after all, JSPs are nothing special, rather another file extension (`<servlet-mapping><url-pattern>*.jsp`) handled by a servlet (the "jsp" servlet) that *happens* to be provided by the server and configured at a server-level. Thus one can override the configuration at web-app level. This is most probably implementation-specific, so it holds for Tomcat *now* but may not be true for Jetty, or for the next version of Tomcat.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos: acceptable reasoning, thanks a lot for the help! I'll debug the implementation a bit to get a better understanding about the servlet.

Answer (score 1):

As Nikos said, You can set the parameters of JspServlet instance by editing the **web.xml** in **${TOMCAT_HOME}/conf** directory. So, that this property will be set in `org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet` instance during server startup. In your case, to set the parameter `compilerTargetVM`, you can edit the `JspServlet` declaration to

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>fork</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>xpoweredBy</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <!-- Added the user parameter -->
          <init-param>
            <param-name>compilerTargetVM</param-name>
            <param-value>1.7</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: So, adding this servlet entry to my application web.xml won't work?

Comment: Yes, you have to do it in the server level

Comment: No, you **CAN** do it in the application web.xml, tested right now with Tomcat 7.0.47, see edit in my answer.

Comment: Really,then a new instance of JspServlet is being created in the app level.Thank you